# System.GC doesnt work on create method

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using System.GC  (GC.CollectorOn xamarin) for clearing Garbage collector.
But unfortunately after i will open the activity more than five times i will get error Java.Lang.outof memory. Why this happened? System.GC doesnt click dynamic all my garbage collector?Here is my Code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.CatalogItem);
    imageview = FindViewById < ImageView > (Resource.Id.ItemImageView);

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    dpPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "student.db3");
    db = new SQLiteConnection(dpPath);
    var table = db.Query < CatalogItemClass > ("select  ItemImg,_id,InventoryItemName,InventoryItemPrice from CatalogItemClass where CategoryID=1  ");

    foreach(var item in table) {
        Image = item.ItemImg;
    }

    if (Image != null) {
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Image, 0, Image.Length);
        imageview.SetImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems in your activity stack there are five same `Activity` instance and they consume lots of heap memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer the only way to run Garbage collector and to work is to close pemenately all elements which you are use in your activity.So when i'm pressing back press i run FinishAffinity.Then in next activity i run system.gc

Answer (score 3):

> But unfortunately after i will open the activity more than five times i will get error Java.Lang.outof memory.

As @elmorabea said, there is something that is leaking memory, memory leak will  causes fewer and fewer available `Heaps` and **triggers `GC` frequently**, but the can't recycle these resource and finally `OOM` happened. In this situation, execute `GC` won't be able to help you.

> So when i'm pressing back press i run FinishAffinity.Then in next activity i run system.gc

You have destroy the object that causes leaking memory so the `GC` could work again. You could use `Android Device Monitor` to find what objects is leaking memory :

[image]

[image]

## Solution :

1. Solve your memory leak issue.
2. Load your bitmap efficiently.

   - You could read this [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/), this recipe shows you how you can load large images into memory without the application throwing an `OutOfMemoryException` by loading a smaller subsampled version in memory.

## Suggestion :

Store image to Sqlite Database is not best practice, you could store images in storage, make them private then keep them inside your app folder and save the path to the Database.

Then you could use some library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to load the image, they did a great job when load image. As their document said, fast and efficient image loading for Android, they could help you to solve the `OOM` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't clear the garbage collector unless you need to. Android will do automatic garbage collection for you.

[Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/)

Comment: I know but it doesnt. I reach the maximum heap size and my apk is crashing.My image is 1,5 mb.Should i realease image every time i'm opening activity or something?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, garbage collector's method to invoke it, is more of a hint that you want GC to run, there is no actual guarantee that it will run immediately.

Secondly, if you have something that is leaking memory, thread holding on to a view instance for example, or something of that sort, GC won't be able to help you.

Have a look `here` at to read further about memory leaks.

At some other cases, it might not be a leak, it just might be that you are loading an image that is simply too big. In that case you either should use a library like Picasso or Glide and use their scaling features.
Or you might want to have a look at a nice attribute to scale images before loading them. [inJustDecodeBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds)